# Only odd primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

For $k \ge 2$, let

$$u = \{\lfloor{(k - \sqrt{k})n}\rfloor : n \ge 1\}$$
$$v = \{\lfloor{(k + \sqrt{k})n}\rfloor : n \ge 1\}.$$

My computer suggests that $u$ and $v$ are disjoint if and only if $k$ is an odd prime.  Can someone give a reference, proof, or counterexample?

Comment: Are $k$ and $n$ integers?

Comment: A tiny bit of data:  $\lfloor(2 - \sqrt2)6\rfloor = \lfloor(2 + \sqrt2)1\rfloor$; $\lfloor(4 - \sqrt4)3\rfloor = \lfloor(4 + \sqrt4)1\rfloor$; $\lfloor(6 - \sqrt6)12\rfloor = \lfloor(6 + \sqrt6)5\rfloor$; $\lfloor(8 - \sqrt8)2\rfloor = \lfloor(8 + \sqrt8)1\rfloor$; $\lfloor(9 - \sqrt9)2\rfloor = \lfloor(9 + \sqrt9)1\rfloor$; and, if I have not made a mistake, then these are the least coincidences among the two sets. Do you know any special case (e.g., non-squarefree $k$ don't produce disjoint sets)?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are disjoint if and only if $k$ is odd and not a perfect square. See my response below.

Answer (score 32):

If $k$ is odd and not a perfect square, then the sets are disjoint. In particular, if $\alpha = \frac{k - \sqrt{k}}{\frac{k-1}{2}}$ and $\beta = \frac{k + \sqrt{k}}{\frac{k-1}{2}}$, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrational and $\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} = 1$. Therefore, by [Beatty's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence),
$A = \{ \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor : n \geq 1 \}$ and $B = \{ \lfloor \beta n \rfloor : n \geq 1 \}$ form a partition of the positive integers. The sets $u$ and $v$ are subsets of $A$ and $B$ respectively (in particular those with $\frac{k-1}{2} \mid n$).

In particular, the sets $u$ and $v$ are disjoint for $k = 15$, which is the smallest non-prime odd number that is not a perfect square.

Comment: And these are all the good $k$'s, be a theorem of Skolem (1957). See my response below.

Answer (score 20):

This is a supplement to Jeremy Rouse's nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415403). Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be positive irrational numbers. Skolem proved in 1957 (see Theorem 8 in [On certain distributions of integers in pairs with given differences](http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/math/article/viewFile/10490/8511)) that the Beatty sequences $[\alpha n]$ and $[\beta n]$ are disjoint if and only if $a/\alpha+b/\beta=1$ holds for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. It follows that the OP's sets $u$ and $v$ are disjoint if and only if $k$ is odd and not a perfect square.

Comment: The last section of the Skolem 1957 paper notes that his results for sets $\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$ are extended to more general sets of the form $\lfloor (\alpha n + \beta) \rfloor$ to appear in Norske Vid. Selsk. Fohr., Trondheim.  Can someone give a URL for that paper?

Comment: @ClarkKimberling The paper is Über einige Eigenschaften der Zahlenmengen $[\alpha n+\beta]$ bei irrationalem $\alpha α$ mit einleitenden Bemerkungen über einige kombinatorische Probleme,  Norske Vid. Selsk. Forh., Trondheim 30 (1957), 42-49. It proves that the sequences $[\alpha n+\gamma]$ and $[\beta n+\delta]$ are disjoint if and only if there are integers $a,b>0$ such that $a/\alpha+b/\beta=1$ and $a\gamma/\alpha+b\delta/\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know an URL for this paper.